# Was vs Has been

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

> Introduce yourself please.
>
> 1. I **have been** a teacher for 10 years.

> 2. I **was** a teacher for 10 years.

Is the sentence 2 correct ?
Can we use "for+period of time" with the past simple tense?

What is the difference between sentences 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Yes, we can! The first sentence(=I'm still teaching now), second sentence(=I retired)

Comment: Thanks a lot but as far as I know the first sentence does not gurantee that I am still teaching , it is different than "I have been teaching for 10 years. Am I correct ?

Comment: "I've been teaching for 10 years"="I've taught for 10 years", just the difference is you emphasize the continuity in the progressive aspect(been teaching..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 1 is present perfect. We use it when something happened in the past but some consequence remains, or the something is still happening:

> I have booked some tickets - *booking took place in the past, but the tickets are still valid*
>   I have been looking for a new flat - *I was looking and I am still looking or have only recently stopped*.

Looking at your sentence:

> 1- I have been a teacher for 10 years.

This means that the speaker started as a teacher ten years ago and is still a teacher at the time of speaking, or has only recently stopped.

Sentence 2 uses simple past: we use this to talk about something that took place in the past, or that continued for some time but is now finished.

> I fell off a ladder - *a single event*
>   I spent a month in Thailand - *it lasted a month, but now it's over*

Looking at your sentence:

2- I was a teacher for 10 years.

This means that the speaker became a teacher and stopped after ten years: this all happened in the past.

As you can see, it is possible to specify a time interval with simple past, as long as the time interval ended well before the time of speaking.

For more information, see the British Council explanation of [talking about the past](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/talking-about-past).

Comment: How is sentence 2 different from 'I had been a teacher for 10 years.'?

Comment: @ShoaibAshraf: "I had been a teacher for 10 years." is not a complete sentence. You use past perfect to specify that something took place before some event in the past, and **you must specify that event in the sentence**. For example, "I had been a teacher for 10 years **when I moved to London**.